# Why my string getting some extra value? (C program)

Tags: c, algorithm

I am trying to solve a C Program problem:

Create a program in C that reads a string from a text file and then reorders the string in an odd-even format (first take odd numbered letters and then even numbered letters; example: if the program reads `elephant`, then the reordered string will be `eehnlpat`). Then write the string in a different text file. Provide an error-checking mechanism for both reading and writing.

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    FILE *inputFile;

    inputFile = fopen("inpFile.txt", "r");

    if (inputFile != NULL) {
        FILE *outFile = fopen("outFile.txt", "w");

        if (outFile != NULL) {
            printf("file created successfully\n");

            int i, j = 0;
            char strf1[50];
            fscanf(inputFile, "%s", &strf1);
            char strf2[strlen(strf1)];
            for (i = 0; strf1[i] > 0; i++) {
                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    strf2[j] = strf1[i];
                    j++;
                }
            }
            for (i = 1; strf1[i] > 0; i++) {
                if (i % 2 == 1) {
                    strf2[j] = strf1[i];
                    j++;
                }
            }
            fprintf(outFile, "%s\n", strf2);

            fclose(outFile);
        } else {
            printf("file could not be created\n");
        }
        fclose(inputFile);
    } else {
        printf("File does not exist.");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I feel all is OK but the problem is if the program reads `elephant`, then the reordered string given by my program is `eehnlpatZ0@`. Where extra `Z0@` is my problem. I don't want that extra thing. But I can't fix it. If anybody can help me to fix it, that will be great.

Comment: change `char strf2[strlen(strf1)];` to `char strf2[strlen(strf1)+1];`. In C strings are null-terminated and you need space for that character.

Comment: `char strf2[strlen(strf1)]` - doesn't leave space for a terminating null char (which you never wrote anyway). Submitting an unterminated string to any of the `printf` family using `%s` invokes *undefined behavior*. You're not complying with the requirements of that format specifier.

Comment: Have you checked through this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270708/string-array-with-garbage-character-at-end
And also this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107826/proper-way-to-empty-a-c-string

Comment: read [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your target string is too short: `char strf2[strlen(strf1)];`. You should at least allow for a null terminator and set it, or simply make the output array the same size as the input array:

```
char strf2[50];
```

There are other problems in your code:

- In case of error by `fopen`, it would be advisable to return a non-zero status to the system.
- You should pass the array to `fscanf()`, not a pointer to the array, which has a different type.
- You should tell `fscanf()` the maximum number of characters to read into the array with `%49s`
- You should test the return value of `fscanf()` and produce an empty output file for an empty input file. The current code has undefined behavior in this case.
- The test `strf1[i] > 0` is incorrect: characters from the input file might be negative. You should either compute the string length or test with `strf1[i] != '\0'`
- Starting the second loop at `i = 1` seems a good idea, but it relies on the silent assumption that `strf1` is not an empty string. In your example, if `fscanf()` succeeds, `strf1` is not empty, and if it fails the behavior is undefined because `strf1` is uninitialized. Yet it is safer to avoid such optimisations which will bite you if you later move the code to a generic function for which the assumption might not hold.
- You must null terminate the output string before passing it to `fprintf` or specify the length with a `%.*s` format.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *inputFile, *outFile;
    char strf1[50], strf2[50];
    int i, j;

    inputFile = fopen("inpFile.txt", "r");
    if (inputFile == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot open input file inpFile.txt\n");
        return 1;
    }
    outFile = fopen("outFile.txt", "w");
    if (outFile == NULL) {
        printf("Could not create output file outFile.txt\n");
        fclose(inputFile);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("file created successfully\n");

    if (fscanf(inputFile, "%49s", strf1) == 1) {
        j = 0;
        for (i = 0; strf1[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                strf2[j++] = strf1[i];
        }
        for (i = 0; strf1[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 1) 
                strf2[j++] = strf1[i];
        }
        strf2[j] = '\0';
        fprintf(outFile, "%s\n", strf2);
    }
    fclose(inputFile);
    fclose(outFile);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is an alternative with simpler copy loops:

```
        int len = strlen(strf1);
        j = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            strf2[j++] = strf1[i];
        }
        for (i = 1; i < len; i += 2) {
            strf2[j++] = strf1[i];
        }
        strf2[j] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide a space for the null-terminator, since you did not provide a space for it, `printf` cannot know when your string is terminated, so it contiues to print out data from the memory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
    FILE* inputFile;

    inputFile=fopen("inpFile.txt", "r");

    if (inputFile!=NULL) {
        FILE* outFile=fopen("outFile.txt", "w");

        if (outFile!=NULL) {
            printf("file created successfully\n");

            int i, j=0;
            char strf1[50];
            fscanf(inputFile, "%s",&strf1);
            int inputLength = strlen(strf1) + 1;
            char strf2[inputLength];
            char strf2[inputLength-1] = '\0';

            for(i=0; strf1[i]>0; i++) {
                if(i%2==0) {
                    strf2[j]=strf1[i];
                    j++;
                }
            }
            for(i=1; strf1[i]>0; i++) {
                if(i%2==1) {
                    strf2[j]=strf1[i];
                    j++;
                }
            }
            fprintf(outFile, "%s\n",strf2);

            fclose(outFile);
        }else{
            printf("file could not be created\n");
        }

        fclose(inputFile);
    }
    else {
        printf("File does not exist.");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: char strf2[inputLength];
            char strf2[inputLength-1] = '\0';
Doesn't even compile

Answer (score 0):

In C, strings require a Null character, '\0', as the last byte in order to terminate.

Changing the following line of code from

```
char strf2[strlen(strf1)];
```

to

```
char strf2[strlen(strf1) + 1];
```

will solve this problem.